# Javascript global variable undefined in function scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to JavaScript and trying to make a simple node server. Here is my code:

```
var activeGames = {}

exports.initialize = function(){
    var gameID = "game12345"
    activeGames.gameID = new Game(gameID, "player1", "player2")
}
```

I call the initialize function from another module, and I get an error stating that activeGames is undefined. activeGames is at the outermost scope of the file. I tried adding 'this' before activeGames.gameID but that did not fix it. Why is activeGames undefined? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here's how I'm calling this code.

In my base index file I have

```
const handler = require("./request-handler.js")
handler.initialize()
```

In request-handler.js, I have

```
var gameManager = require('./game-manager')

exports.initialize = function(){
    gameManager.initialize()
}
```

Comment: How are you importing/calling the function in the other module? Can you add that code to your question?

Comment: You are not exporting the variable.

Comment: @JulianSoto I don't want the variable to be accessible from a different module, I just want to use it in that function. Do I still need to export it for that?

Comment: @JulianSoto he is not trying to export the variable, he's trying to export a function which affects a variable.
I can't find something wrong with your code. I will try it myself and edit my comment :)

Comment: @Connor Using global variables is not a good pattern/best practice.

Comment: @JulianSoto I understand that, but I don't know JS well enough to know how to properly avoid having it be global. Really I just need it to be accessible in a few functions within this file.

Comment: I ran the code and it works perfectly. Maybe you should trying changing the `exports.initialize` in `request-handler.js` to `exports.initialize = gameManager.initialize;`.

Comment: @Connor If you want to use the variable in other functions define it in a separate module and import this module if is needed, you can do it one or more times. Or simple define your variable within the main function and pass it as parameter to the modules.

Comment: @TamirNahum No luck

Comment: @Connor which file are you running?

Comment: @TamirNahum I'm creating the node server from index.js

Comment: Does it work if you do away with "function" and write it as follows `exports.initialize = ()=>{
    var gameID = "game12345"
    activeGames.gameID = new Game(gameID, "player1", "player2")
}`

Comment: What is the exact error you are facing? Would you like to share with us the `Game` class you just made?

Comment: @Connor I cannot reproduce your error. The code you posted works fine for me.

Comment: If this is code running in a node module, the above code does NOT result in a global variable.

Comment: Please show the code that produces the reported error. Is it, or is it not, because you attempted to access `activeGames` outside the module it is defined in?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has lexical scope, not dynamic scope. 
ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping

Lexical scope means that whether a variable is accessible or not depends on where they appear in the source text, it doesn't depend on runtime information.

example:

```
function foo() {
  var bar = 42;
  baz();
}

function baz() {
  console.log(bar); // error because bar is not in the scope of baz
}
```

the same problem happens in your code,

> var activeGames

is not in scope.

try this variation:

```
exports.initialize = function(){
    var activeGames = {}
    var gameID = "game12345"
    activeGames.gameID = new Game(gameID, "player1", "player2")
}
```

A good solution could be to use a class and export it:
--THIS CODE IS NOT TESTED--

```
class gamesManager {
   var activeGames = {}

   initialize() {
      var gameID = "game12345"
      activeGames.gameID = new Game(gameID, "player1", "player2")
   }
}

exports.gamesManager = gamesManager
```

USE:

```
const activeGames = require('./game-manager');
const activeGamesInstance = new activeGames.gamesManager();
activeGamesInstance.initialize();
```

Comment: Ok, but I want to use activeGames in other functions

Comment: I can't find a reason to export the `activeGames` object. I ran his code and it's working perfectly.

Comment: I only need to use it in this module. Is there a way I can group the contents of this module other than just keeping it in the same file? For example, in Java I'd make it a class.

Comment: i think that a good idea for refactor your code could be to create a cass and export it instead of a function.

Comment: @TamirNahum Run the code in 'strict mode' and see the fireworks.

Comment: @JulianSoto also works perfectly with `strict mode`. Please quote your error and the `Game` class.

Comment: Can you explain why *var activeGames is not in scope*?

Comment: activeGames IS in the outer scope and will continue to be available in the initialize() function after the original code runs - that's one of the things you get with closures.

Also, not sure what strict mode has to do about this - the original poster is writing a Node module.  Declaring `var foo` in a Node module doesn't result in an unintentional global window variable like in the browser.

Comment: @le_m look at the example, the the variable activeGames is not in the module that calls the function initialize

Comment: @DaniloCalzetta But it's in the scope of the module containing the 'initialize' function expression. Since this variable binding is lexical, the context from where we call that initialize function shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: @le_m you are right, I think it is necessary to rethink the approach. If I have to call stateless functions I usually create functions in the module, but if I need to maintain the state then I normally build a class that has state variables inside. Moreover thinking about the problem in itself I think that Connor has to modify his code using of objects and not functions.

Answer (score 1):

Need a code sample for this one.  I ran this locally and it worked fine, although your code has a big issue which may be a part of your problem.  It looks like you want to keep track of multiple games in `activeGames`.  You need to use this syntax instead:

```
activeGames[gameID] = new Game(gameID, "player1", "player2")
```

Here's my working code:

`index.js`:

```
const handler = require("./request-handler");

handler.initialize('game-1234');
handler.initialize('game-5678');
```

`request-handler.js`:

```
var gameManager = require('./game-manager');

exports.initialize = function(gameID) {
    gameManager.initialize(gameID);
}
```

`game-manager.js`:

```
var activeGames = {};

class Game {
    constructor(id, player1, player2) {
        this.id = id;
        this.player1 = player1;
        this.player2 = player2;
    }
}

exports.initialize = function(gameID) {
    activeGames[gameID] = new Game(gameID, "player1", "player2");

    console.log(`game initialized! ${ Object.keys(activeGames).length } active games`);
}
```

Running `node index` results in this:

```
game initialized! 1 active games
game initialized! 2 active games
```

Answer (score 1):

When you require a script file in Node.js, it is compiled as part of a function called with named parameters `require`, `module`, `exports` and other exposed variables as arguments<sup>1</sup>. Variables declared at file level within the required script become function level variables in the enclosing module wrapper and retained inside its closure.

Hence your "global variable" is no such thing: it's a variable defined inside a closure...

An important question then is does the module loader make variables declared in a parent module available to scripts required inside the parent. A quick test shows that the answer is general: **no, modules do not have automatic access to variables declared in other modules** - those variables are inside closures.

This indicates that to pass variable values to scripts that have been required, generally pass them as argument values to exported functions.

It is also possible to export any javascript value as a property of `module.exports` from within a required script, or add properties to an `exports` object after it has been returned from requiring a script. Hence it is technically feasible to pass information up and down between modules by adding properties to `exports` objects.

Redesigned code has multiple options to

1. define `activeGames` at the application level and pass it down as a parameter to modules needing access to it, or
2. export `activeGames` from `game-manager.js` by adding

   ```
     exports.activeGames = activeGames
   ```

   to the end of the file. This will not take care of exporting `activeGames` out of the parent module `request-manager.js` for use elsewhere, but it could be a start. Or
3. define `activeGames` as a global variable (in node) using

   ```
     global.activeGames = {}  // define a global object
   ```

   Defining global variables is not encouraged as it can lead to collisions (and consequent program failure) between names used by applications, code libraries, future library updates and future versions of ECMAScript. Or,
4. Define an application namespace object for data global to the application. Require it wherever access to application data is needed:

   - create `appdata.js` as an empty file.
     Optionally include a comment:

     ```
      // this files exports module.exports without modification
     ```
   - require `appdata.js` wherever needed.

     ```
     var appData = require('./appdata.js')
     appData.gameData = {}; // for example
     ```

   This relies on node.js maintaining a cache of previously required modules and does not recompile modules simply because they have been required a second time. Instead it returns the `exports` object of the previous `require`.

Happy festive season.

---

References
<sup>1</sup>[The Node.js Way - How `require()` Actually Works](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/)

Comment: Insightful explanation, but does it answer OP's question "*Why is activeGames undefined*"?

Comment: @le_m it does if the error is caused by attempting to access `activeGames` outside the module it's defined in. It is not a global variable and the question title suggests an assumption that it is. I've asked the OP to clarify in the post.